# HTML5/Ajax chat room

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, database

I'm planning to do an html based chatroom. This is a multi-user chat room and the expected users chatting at a time would be around 5k. My initial thoughts would be,  the page chat would have a javascript ajax call every 5 seconds to fetch the latest messages from the chat room. However, this upon fetching the messages it would appear like all of them has been sent t time same time.  Eg: a wall of text every 5 seconds. To resolve this I tought of using server generated timestamps and have the javascript call display these messages after one another depending on the time stamp.

Now the problem would be the database and the server handling this. The messages needs to be saved on a database so that new visitors will be able to scroll up and see the past chats. Now Im starting to imagine,  5k users querying the db every 5 seconds would kill a server.

Is there a better way to design a real time html based chat? It will need to be in php.

Another thing that came to mind is to use php as a server and utilize its socket functions. However I am not sure how this would be done.

Comment: 3 down votes and not one comment to explain why.... I really hate that.

Comment: webrtc with websockets supporting server would be the way to go. PHP is not really the best for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really pretty new technology that is taking over the social specter of the internet that is exactly what you need. It is called websockets. I apologize I cannot provide any links at the moment but you could search for it. In case you don't feel like learning how this new technology works or it seems too complicated you can always use LONG POLLING. But if you decide to go with long polling have in mind that certain servers have a limit to open connections! I hope this answer was helpful to you and I wish you good luck in your project!